# Relative positioning for an absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` which is absolutely positioned. Now this `<div>` has child elements which will be absolutely positioned relative to parent `<div>`. If I set the position of parent `<div>` to relative to keep its child elements in place, the parent `<div>` is getting out of its actual position.

How to solve this? I need to make parent `<div>` element which is absolutely positioned, relative to its child element who are absolute.

html:

```
<div class="tooltip" style="right:200px">
   Hover over me<span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  left: 110%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Save people the hassle of writing out and/or guessing what your html and css are, if they want to experiment with the problem.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve]. And please proof-read your question before (or at least directly after) submitting it, because then you should have seen that all the `<div>`s had "vanished"

Comment: what you're explaining should already work. Absolute child elements will be positioned relative to the closest _positioned_ parent, that includes an `absolute` positioned parent, the parent doesn't have to be `relative` positioned

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xfd5aegj/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.tooltip.tooltiptext
```

should be

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext
```

without the space denotes the same element with multiple class names e.g.

`class="tooltip tooltiptext"`

which is not what you have

with the space denotes a parent - child relationship, which is what you have, i.e -

```
<div class="tooltip">
   <span class="tooltiptext">...</span>
</div>
```

Edit... I see the question has been edited by another user to now show `.tooltip .tooltiptext` so I have no idea what the original poster actually as in their code, but the original question showed `.tooptip.tooltiptext`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I was doing the same, edited the question